# How to repeat table in jasper report based on grouped data from SQL

Tags: jasper-reports

This is the output from my SQL query
[image]

I am trying to create a report in Jasper Studio which will create a separate table for each city.

[image]

Right now, what I have created is something that looks like below. It shows all the data with the City listed as St. Louis. What features in Jasper will allow me to do as above?

[image]

Comment: `What features in Jasper will allow me to do as above?` - [Grouping](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#groups), for example

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out.

1. Create a group band for your report in Jasper. (Right click report Outline-> Create Group)
2. Next you have two options - create group from a report object or create group from expression. I used the first option and selected City from the list of group objects displayed. Click Next.
3. Selected the checkbox Add the group header and click finish.

The other change I did was - Previously my headers were under column header, I moved them under the new band group header. Now it works exactly like how I wanted.